# Output curly brace in JSF h:outputText

Tags: jsf, el

I want to use the following EL inside a custom component:

```
<ui:param name="valueAfter"
    value="#{not empty valueAfter ? valueAfter : false}" />
<h:outputText
    value="#{x.label}#{valueAfter == true ? {x.value} : ''}" />
```

This does not work as I cannot output the curly braces around `x.value` but now I am looking for a good way to actually output those.

Comment: does adding `escape="true"` helps ?

Comment: No, that doesn't help, tried that.

Comment: how about `? '{'x.value'}' : ''` or adding `\\` before the `{`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<h:outputText value="#{x.label"}/>
<h:outputText value="{#{x.value}}" rendered="#{valueAfter}"/>
```

Comment: That did the trick ... I was so fixed onto putting it all into one `outputText`, I didn't even try to split it up. Although now I have to copy and paste all other attributes among those three `outputText`s, but at least it works ... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go -In case you are using *EL 2* (I think), one line with one `h:outputText` solution thanks to the `.concat()`

```
<h:outputText value="#{x.label}#{valueAfter == true?'{'.concat(x.value).concat('}'):''}" />
```